# Can I bring sausages on a plane?

Tags: sausages, food-transport

I'd like to bring some raw Italian sausages with me when I fly from NYC to Seattle.

- Is it legal to pack sausages and/or ice in a carry-on?
- Will the sausages keep during the 6-hour flight?

Comment: Legality isn't really a cooking question; you could ask on the travel stackexchange. That said... food is fine. And I'm pretty sure you can *check* coolers. Bringing them as a carry-on would be harder. I'm sure the cooler itself would be fine if it's within the size limits, but since you can't bring liquids through security, you'd have to get the ice from somewhere past security.

Comment: Sorry, legal advice is off topic. If you remove that part, the question "will it keep" will be closed as a duplicate: Any non-refrigerated food item which usually requires refrigeration is considered safe for 2 hours at temperatures between 4 and 60°C, and we have answered lots of questions about that.

Comment: @rumtscho: "Will it keep" can admittedly be transformed into "what's necessary to keep something cold for 6 hours", which is what I optimistically assumed the OP meant to ask.

Comment: I imagine using dry ice would be enough to bypass the "no liquids" rule, but there might be other regulations pertaining to food products or raw meat.

Comment: @user5561, dry ice is sufficiently hazardous that there's good reason to ban it on planes, unlike water ice.

Answer (score 1):

"Will they keep" is mostly a matter of how well you pack them. With sufficient ice, of course they'll keep. And if you freeze the sausage first, it won't take nearly as much ice to keep them cold - they probably wouldn't even thaw all the way through if left out at room temperature for 6 hours.